# Почему не работает массив?

Tags: java, android, activity

Я использую `onSaveInstanceState()` и `onRestoreInstanceState()`, чтобы сохранить позицию картинки после перезапуска активити. Но данный метод почему-то не работает - после рестарта массив работает сначала. В чём проблема?

```
int[] array_images = {
            R.drawable.p_orange,
            R.drawable.p_banana,
            R.drawable.p_apple,
    };
    int index = -1;
private void updateImage()
  {
    index++;
    if(index >= array_images.length)
      index = 0;
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(array_images[index]);
  }

@Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putIntArray("array_images", array_images);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

  }
  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    array_images = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("array_images");

  }
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          dialog.dismiss();
          finish();
          startActivity(getIntent());
          updateImage();
        }

      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Позиция картинки храниться в переменной `index`, но вы её значение почему-то не сохраняете, а сохраняете массив. Замените

```
outState.putIntArray("array_images", array_images);
```

на

```
outState.putInt("index", index);
```

и

```
array_images = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("array_images");
```

на

```
index = savedInstanceState.getInt("index");
```

Comment: Блин, я тоже хотел это написать, но вы меня опередили)

Comment: идея замечательная, но, к сожалению, не работает

Comment: @A.Schtolc перезапуск активити - что вы под ним подразумеваете?поворот экрана, или выйти и  зайти в приложение заново?

Comment: @Asgard я перезапускаю активити *startActivity(getIntent());*, чтобы обновить на нём контент

Comment: @Asgard, вы неправильно понимаете назначение `onSaveInstanceState`.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja вполне возможно - пользуюсь им, эм. Не пользуюсь. Просто хотел исключить тот момент, когда бывает люди предполагают использовать его как `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, значение индекса надо сохранять в настройках в методах onPause() и onResume():

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("index", index);
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    index = preferences.getInt("index", -1);
}
```